# How to know if vector is undefined

Tags: vector, vhdl

### What I have

I've a signal of `std_logic_vector`. I need to give it values from a ROM, what I already do.

### The problem

At the beginning of the simulation or use, there's an initialization process which makes it to need some time before ROM returns it first value (about 2 clk period).

Until then, ROM output vector is "UUUU" (since it's 4 bits of width). Let's call this signal `ROM_coef_inf`, so in simulation, this appears with "UUUU" value, so its colour is orange.

### I need

I need to know how can I compare this output in order to know if it's an "undefined vector", in order to give another value (i.e. "0000") to my vector until the first ROM value is ready.

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible solutions:

1. You could initialize all registers between your ROM and your destination (at least in simulation) with a different value to `"UUUU"`.
2. A standard compare can test for all 9 `STD_LOGIC` values:
   `if (mySignal == 'U') then`
3. You can test signals for special values with `is_x(...)`.
   Is is defined like this:

   ```
   FUNCTION Is_X ( s : std_ulogic) RETURN  BOOLEAN IS
   BEGIN
     CASE s IS
       WHEN 'U' | 'X' | 'Z' | 'W' | '-' => RETURN TRUE;
       WHEN OTHERS => NULL;
     END CASE;
     RETURN FALSE;
   END;
   ```

   There are overload for vectors, too.

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by @Paebbels works only in simulation. In the real world the signals tend to be either an 1 or a 0 (or a transition between them, but that is not discussed here). Number 1 will work, but you need to set it to a value that will never occur in your ROM if you want to check for uninitialized. The simpler option is to count clock cycles. The ROM will always behave the same. So if it takes three cycles to get the first data out, it will always take three cycles. So if you count three cycles you are ok.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is for FPGA use, in which case all registers will have a predictable value after programming, which is zeros unless you specify something else. If all you need is for `ROM_coef_inf` to have zeros instead of U's for the first clock cycles in simulation, you can simply specify an initial value when declaring the signal:

```
signal ROM_coef_inf : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) := "0000";
```

In ASICs registers will have an unknown value after power is applied. In this case you need to use a reset signal to clear all the registers in your design. It is often a good idea to use a reset signal in an FPGA as well, for example to prevent your circuit from doing anything until the clock is stable.